# Syntax error: unexpected "("

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I keep trying to launch this vim sh file but i keep getting the error message `Syntex error: unexpected "("`

```
#!/bin/bash

openssl req -x509 -out pop1001234.cert -keyout pop1001234.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Comment: You have to execute it with bash, not sh.

Comment: thanks it worked i don't know why but it only works in bash even if in the file i do #!/bin/sh it still doesn't work

Comment: `<(...)` is a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) which is a bash feature not found in /bin/sh.

Comment: Also, inside the parentheses, you can put any script, so newlines are allowed: you don't need the backslash line continuation.

Comment: To clarify, if you run your script as `./script.sh` will evaluate `#!` as expected, but running the script as `sh ./script.sh` (or `bash ./script.sh`) will handle `#!` as an ordinary comment.